# Whats the difference for Expires using Plus in htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, cache-control

What is the difference between these two lines?

```
ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType application/javascript "access 1 year"
```

Do they mean the same thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [`mod_expires` manual](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_expires.html#AltSyn):

> The `ExpiresDefault` and `ExpiresByType` directives can also be defined in a more readable syntax of the form:
>
> `ExpiresDefault "base [plus num type] [num type] ..."`
>   `ExpiresByType type/encoding "base [plus num type] [num type] ..."`
>
> where *base* is one of:
>
> - `access`
> - `now` (equivalent to '`access`')
> - `modification`
>
> **The plus keyword is optional**. num should be an integer value [acceptable to `atoi()`], and type is one of:
>
> - `years`
> - `months`
> - `weeks`
> - `days`
> - `hours`
> - `minutes`
> - `second`

So no - there's no difference.